# javascript image onclick won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, onclick

I want to click on a image and that it changes into another but it wont work,
i used the code from w3schools.com but it won't work either

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="img/checkoff.png">

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if (image.src.match("checkon")) {
            image.src = "checkoff.png";
        } else {
            image.src = "checkon.png";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you received any errors ?

Comment: in the if / else statements, you have to add the folder to the image name. `image.src = 'img/checkoff.png'` and `image.src = 'img.checkon.png'`

Comment: There are lot of modification needed to make it work

Comment: It should work. Although it won't find `checkoff.png` or `checkon.png`. You need `img/checkoff.png` and likewise.

Comment: @shv22 That is absolutely wrong. This has nothing to do with `jquery` or any other library.

Comment: code seems fine to me, it's working like expected https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/nphtr5xz/ I added `alt` attribute to see if it works since the images are missing. Just need to add `img/` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a issue in your code

here you use only name of image file with extension you need to also give a relative file path of image: like this

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("checkon")) {
        image.src = "img/checkoff.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "img/checkon.png";
    }
}
```

Here you can check this example.

It is working smoothly.

Hope this will helps you

```js
function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if (image.src.match("generic-image-placeholder")) {
            image.src = "https://cdn.noths-static.com/system/product_images/images/001/037/649/original_set-of-eight-white-heart-name-place-holders.jpg";
        } else {
            image.src = "https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/images/cdn.designinstruct.com/files/582-how-to-image-placeholders/generic-image-placeholder.png";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="https://cdn.noths-static.com/system/product_images/images/001/037/649/original_set-of-eight-white-heart-name-place-holders.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code is working

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://fakeimg.pl/300/">

<script>
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (image.src.match("http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/")) {
    image.src = "http://fakeimg.pl/300/";
  } else {
    image.src = "http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/";
  }
}
</script>
```

[Click Here to see jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/u1u1p7dL/)

Your code please change path when click on image

```
<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if (image.src.match("checkon.png")) {
            image.src = "img/checkoff.png";
        } else {
            image.src = "img/checkon.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Image path is not correct in your code. Please update as below :

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (image.src.match("checkon")) {
image.src = "img/checkoff.png";
} else {
image.src = "img/checkon.png";
}
}
</script>
```